# Load all entities attached to an object (ignore lazy loading)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I wonder if there is a way to tell NHibernate to fetch all data from the DB into the object-graph, no matter if in the mapping-files lazy-loading is set to true. Is there such a function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two options that I'm aware of:

### Use the `NHibernateUtil` class

For example:

```
Order fromDb;
using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    fromDb = session.Get<Order>(_order.Id);
    NHibernateUtil.Initialize(fromDb.Customer);
}
```

That will force eager loading of the `Customer` entity.

### Use HQL `fetch`

If you're using HQL to fetch your entities, just use the `fetch` keyword in order to force eager loading:

```
from Order o
inner join fetch o.OrderLines
inner join fetch o.Customer
where o.Id = :id
```

In that example, `OrderLines` and `Customer` will be eager loaded.

More details [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/lazy-loading-eager-loading.aspx).

Comment: I see - but then I still need to define in any case what I wan't to fetch and I can't do that implicitly, right? If I have a complex graph (with children of children etc.) I still would need to setup the query? The thing is I wan't to create a copy of a complex graph and I thought I would load and then detach everything. Before detaching, everything needs to be loaded though.

Comment: That is what NHibernateUtil.Initialize is for. However, if you have a lot of entities it might have some performance issues.

Comment: Not really - or I could do `NHibernateUtil.Initialize(fromDb);` and `Customer` and `OrderLines` would be loaded, which is not the case.

Answer (score 8):

You can also specify eager fetching in your criterias, for the selected collections:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Post))
.SetFetchMode("Comments", FetchMode.Eager)
.List();
```

You can also combine this with Future<>() invokations for better performance.